# Socket io instance/middleware in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

```
var http = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
server.listen(8080);
```

Above code work if I put in different route. But how to create an instance of it so that I don't have to declare many times?

Comment: *"if I put in different route"* - what route? I don't see any routes

Comment: you can simply exports the module or instance `exports.pool = pool;` where *pool* is function and instance

Answer (score 0):

you are not clear with your question but i think you want to you io object in different files
you can do this using

```
app.all("*",function(req,res,next){
        req.io=io;
        next();
    });
```

define this middleware before the routing in you server file
and where you want to use this you can get this object as

```
function(req,res,next){
 var io = req.io;
}
```